# My cookie is misbehaving.

Tags: php, cookies

**Warning:** *Reading this may make you smile and/or laugh or/at very least chuckle. Mild humor injected for your benefit. Making you smile is my way of showing gratitude for your time.*

The cookie is being `set` successfully, *or is it?*

```
setcookie("REF", $referer, strtotime( '+30 days' ) );
print_r($_COOKIE);
```

When coming from a referring site, I get `[REF] => site`, which is working properly. Next, I open a **new tab** and go to the URL directly. Again, I get `[REF] => site` - great it appears to be working!

*But wait*, don't get too excited. That "appearance" of it working is apparently misleading. It's an illusion; deja-vu of that damned kool-aid machine in the dessert --- all over again. Anyways, I hit `f5` and refresh the page and now the madness begins.

Guess what happens? Did you guess? Here, I'll just tell you; the cookie is no longer *set*. `Array()` *is empty*.  What the frick?

Tested in Chrome and Firefox and the result is the same in both.

***Question:***
How do I make the cookie persist until expired? Why/How does refreshing the page break the cookie? *Bonus:* Is it possible for a cookie set in `Chrome` to automatically be set in `Firefox`? (I'm assuming, NO way! But sometimes I like to think *ANYTHING* is possible)

Comment: +1 for the question. Is your computer time set to Oct 17th?

Comment: I have found that being digested is a reasonable punishment for bad behavior in cookie society.

Comment: The code is doing what you are telling it to do. It's overwriting the cookie on every refresh. The referer is  gone on the subsequent request, but it takes another refresh for it to show up

Comment: @Pekka웃 why is that as I am setting a 30 day to expiry? Why is `Chrome` eating my cookie?

Comment: @fabio — Because when you assign a new cookie with the same name as an existing cookie, the old cookie is overwritten no matter what the expiry date is.

Comment: So you're telling me I have to check if the cookie is set and if `yes` don't assign a new cookie. I eat my cookies in pairs of pairs. I likes cookies.

Comment: Yes, only set the cookie one time. If the cookie is already digested, DO NOT try to eat it again. Bad things.

Comment: uhh what a naughty cookie :x

Comment: @Quentin Thank you. You have solved my cookie problem. By using an `if` block, I get the expected outcome. I just assumed this was built into the function. --- Now, how about my *bonus* question?

Comment: @BrianDHall, but digested cookies are easier to eat if you don't have teeth. :) lol

Comment: Oh, as far as I know no - each browser keeps a very tight lid on it's own jar. Browser's don't like to share.

Comment: Oh, technically you could have a plugin or some external program synchronize cookies across browsers, but you'd have to install them and they'd have to have administrator privileges on most systems.

Comment: There is no sane way to share cookies across browsers - nor should there be a need really. Maybe share what you're trying to do and someone may come up with an alternative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Since no one posted an answer. I will do it for the benefit of the community.*

For the cookie to not be reset on each subsequent page load, you **must use** an `if` statement to check if a cookie already exists before giving out a new one. (I guess we don't want to make people/browsers fat, or we're just stingy with the cookies).

The working code is:

```
If ($_COOKIE == null) { 
    setcookie("REF", $referer, strtotime( '+30 days' ) );
}
```

Special thanks to @Quentin for pointing that out.

Comment: That isn't going to work well as it will neve rbe true if any other cookie is set on the domain. Check for the actual cookie you're trying to set

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. How do I check for the actual cookie? should I do `$_COOKIE["REF"]` or is there another way of checking for a specific cookie?

Comment: `if (!array_key_exists("REF", $COOKIE) or ($_COOKIE["REF"] == "")) ...` should be fine: it checks first whether maybe "REF" doesn't exist at all, and if it does, it checks whether it is empty.